# determine outer boundaries of square islands

Tags: sql, t-sql

This might be impossible but you never know.

I have a bunch of squares in a table Squares consisting of PK, TopLeftLatitude, TopLeftLongitude, LowerRightLatitude, LowerRightLongitude and a bunch of countries in a table called Countries consisting of PK, CountryName. There is a m:m relationship between countries and squares so I also have a table CountriesSquares consisting of PKCountry, PKSquare.

I would like to determine the outer points of neighbouring squares given some countries/squares using SQL. Obviously some countries might consist of ‘islands of squares’ which makes this more complicated ...

Do you think that’s possible? Any feedback would be very much welcome.

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

PS:

Let us say these are two neighboring squares (very simple example):

5, 1, 3, 3
5, 3, 3, 5

The result would be

5, 1, 3, 5

I guess I could do this in C# by looping over everything and checking things but I am looking for a set-based approach which probably involves tie breakers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by determine outer points of neighbouring squares? Can you give an example?

Comment: see PS hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps have a temp table with the data - PK, TopLeftLatitude, TopLeftLongitude, LowerRightLatitude, LowerRightLongitude, LowerLeftLatitude, LowerLeftLongitude, TopRightLatitude, TopRightLongitude. - That means storing all the coordinates of all the corners of the square. Since you mention these are squares, I bet you can find 2 diagonally opposite coordinates of a square knowing the other two.

Now, find the records for a given country and look for the co ordinates which do not have any common co-ordinates with adjacent squares i.e for example look for combination of (TopLeftLatitude, TopLeftLongitude) which are not equal to (TopRightLatitude,TopRightLongitude) or (LowerLeftLatitude,LowerLeftLongitude) or (LowerRightLatitude,LowerRightLongitude).

Performing similar checks for (TopRightLatitude,TopRightLongitude) and (LowerLeftLatitude,LowerLeftLongitude) and (LowerRightLatitude,LowerRightLongitude) will give you the outer most co-ordinates. I am guessing this should work even with islands as it will give you all the exterior co-ordinates (latitude and longitude), how many ever.

Comment: Thanks I have a look at this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If restating your question as "How can I find the top left and bottom right coordinates of a square which encloses a set of known squares" is correct then an approach might be:

1. Move the know square values into a table
2. Add the appropiate value to the coordinates such that all values are positive

EX square 1 = Top Left -5,2 (lat,long) Bottom Right -7,5 (lat,long)
   square 2 = Top Left 3,3 (lat,long)  Bottom Right -10,4 (lat,long)
Table values after normalization by adding 10 to make all values positive (Llat,Llong,Rlat,Rlong)

Square1 5,2,3,15

Square2 13,13,0,4

The max(Llat), min(Llong) should be the TopLeft and the min(L1lat), max(L1long)  should be the bottom right.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately its not that easy as it can be rugged (no overall square) and it can have holes in it.

Answer (score -1):

I was asked something similar in a written interview test once. I wrote that I didn't know but gave some examples of ways not to do it. They offered me the job.

When I got home, I looked it up and found a formula for doing it. Unfortunately, I can't remember what the formula was called, but it was named after somebody. So the answer to your question is "Yes, there is", but you might get more marks for saying "Not that I know of".

Comment: This is not for a test but a problem I am trying to tackle but thanks for nothing.

Comment: No worries. You said "Any feedback would be very much welcome", so I just gave you my feedback.